# Using Invoke-WebRequest to get XML from a printer

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm having trouble getting Invoke-WebRequest to follow a redirected URL.

The URL in question is the management page for a Konica Bizhub printer for which I'm trying retrieve status information for.

From what I can tell, the redirect flow is like this:

- http://1.1.1.1 (IP address of the printer)
- redirects too: http://1.1.1.1/wcd/index.html
- redirects too: http://1.1.1.1/wcd/index.html?access=SYS_INF
- redirects too: http://1.1.1.1/wcd/init.js
- redirects too: http://1.1.1.1/wcd/system_device.xml (stopping point and what appears in the address bar)

The `access=SYS_INF` logs the web session in with a generic user account that has read-only access (which is fine for me).

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
$userAgent = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::Chrome
$url = "http://1.1.1.1/wcd/index.html?access=SYS_INF"
$req = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UserAgent $userAgent
write-host $req
```

which produces this output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta content="text/javascript" http-equiv="Content-Script-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wcd/default.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wcd/init.js"></script>
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/wcd/js_error.xml">
</noscript>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#ffffff" LINK="#000000" ALINK="#ff0000" VLINK="#000000" onload="init('/wcd/system_device.xml','wcd','usr=S_INF;','','param=;',0);">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The line `init('/wcd/system_device.xml...` indicates that the page should be loading the `system_device.xml` page but it doesn't happen.  I suspect that this is not a normal redirection however I don't know how to get PS to follow to the final URL.

I do know that the `access=SYS_INF` needs to be the first URL hit so that a user can be logged in and then `system_device.xml` can be rendered.  So you can't just jump straight to `http://1.1.1.1/wcd/system_device.xml` and load the XML that way.

I've also tried saving the session to a variable and calling it again with another webrequest to no avail:

```
$userAgent = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::Chrome
$url = "http://1.1.1.1"
$req = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable session -UserAgent $userAgent
$req2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -WebSession $session
write-host $req2
```

Similar output as above except that this line is different:
`<BODY BGCOLOR="#ffffff" LINK="#000000" ALINK="#ff0000" VLINK="#000000" onload="location.replace('/wcd/index.html');" >`

Any suggestions would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Consider using SNMP to retrieve information from a printer. This is superior to web scraping by an order of magnitude. Every tiny bit of information a printer collects internally is available through SNMP, much more than typically is exposed through the web interface.

Comment: The `init` is a JavaScript function -- you need a working JavaScript engine to process it, like your web browser has, but PowerShell does not. There's no way to get it to "run" that function. It may do interesting and essential things like set a client-side cookie that the new page needs, or worse, it might do all the client-side rendering on its own. You'll have to bite the bullet and reverse engineer it. (But also, what Tomalak said. This setup is clearly not friendly to automated processing.)

Comment: There are many tools that can talk SNMP and lend themselves to command line use, start with an "SNMP walk" tool that dumps pretty much everything a networked device can tell you. Random Google hit (there are others) https://syslogwatcher.com/cmd-tools/snmp-walk/

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I actually started this little endeavor with SNMP in mind but Konica doesn't provide the MIBs (or API/SDK) for their printers for free so there's a fair amount of reverse engineering that needs to be done to get the info I wanted.  However the XML output provided everything I wanted - printer status, print/scan/fax logs, toner levels, etc - but I fear that Jeroen is correct that the Java processing is going to require even more reverse engineering than SNMP will :/

So, SNMP it is - thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Like you i was unable to get the information I needed from a Konica Minolta bizhub using Invoke-WebRequest, instead I used InternetExplorer.Applcation ComObject to get the details I needed and redirect past the JavaScript init.

```
        # Create Internet Explorer ComObject
        $ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
        
        # Save the Window Handle for later use
        $IEWindowHandle = $ie.HWND

        # Navigate to our URL in this case
        # "http://1.1.1.1/wcd/index.html?access=SYS_INF"
        $ie.Navigate2($url)
```

Additionally, if you receive **RPC_E_DISCONNECTED** you may have to Reconnect to the IE Window Handle

```
 $ShellApp = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

        try 
        {
            $EA = $ErrorActionPreference; $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
            $RecoveredIE = $ShellApp.Windows() | Where-Object {$_.HWND -eq $IEWindowHandle}
        } 
        catch 
        {
            # Shell.Application may not find the window immediately, sleep 500ms 
            Write-debug "Window Handle not Found, Attempting reconnect in 500ms" 
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
            try 
            {
                $RecoveredIE = $ShellApp.Windows() | Where-Object {$_.HWND -eq $IEWindowHandle}
            } 
            catch 
            {
                Write-debug "Could not reconnect InternetExplorer.Application ComObject"
                $RecoveredIE = $null
            }     
        } 
        finally 
        { 
            $ErrorActionPreference = $EA
            $ShellApp = $null
        }
```